# How do I get multiple readings(binary) based on my arduino output?

Tags: arduino-mega, serial-data

I am new to arduino and therefore not much experience in handling codes, please be forgiving and help me!

For my school project, make use of arduino to make 4 capacitive sensors (which has already been successful). Now I am trying to make use of the 4 sensors to be shown in a table format(one for each output) so that I can use that data to be plotted into either Excel or Matlab. Hence I would like to ask how do I group up my data into different columns? Also is it possible to get convert my results into binary format so that it would be easier when trying to plot the data?

My arduino code is here:

```
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>

CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_4 = CapacitiveSensor(2,4); // 1M resistor between pins 4 & 8, pin 8 is sensor pin, add a wire and or foil
CapacitiveSensor   cs_5_7 = CapacitiveSensor(5,7);
CapacitiveSensor   cs_8_10 = CapacitiveSensor(8,10);
CapacitiveSensor   cs_11_13 = CapacitiveSensor(11,13);
void setup()                    
{
   cs_2_4.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);// turn off autocalibrate on channel 1 - just as an example
   cs_5_7.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
   cs_8_10.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
   cs_11_13.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
 Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()                    
{
 long sensor1 =  cs_2_4.capacitiveSensor(50);
 long sensor2 =  cs_5_7.capacitiveSensor(50);
 long sensor3 =  cs_8_10.capacitiveSensor(50);
 long sensor4 =  cs_11_13.capacitiveSensor(50);

Serial.println(sensor1);  // print sensor output 
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(sensor2);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(sensor3);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(sensor4);
 if(sensor1 >= 1000)
   {
    digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
   }
  else{
    digitalWrite(3,LOW);
   }
     if(sensor2 >= 1000)
   {
    digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
   }
   else{
    digitalWrite(6,LOW);
   }  
    if(sensor3 >= 1000)
   {
    digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
   }
   else{
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);
   }  
    if(sensor4 >= 1000)
   {
    digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
   }
   else{
    digitalWrite(12,LOW);
   }  



   }
```

And with that code above the output I receive when I use the serial monitor is:

[image]

Comment: Serial.println() add a CR/LF after printing.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Serial.println(sensor1);  // print sensor output 
> Serial.print("\t");
> Serial.println(sensor2);
> Serial.print("\t");
> Serial.println(sensor3);
> Serial.print("\t");
> Serial.println(sensor4);
> ```

If you want 4 columns don't use `println` for each number, as that starts a new line.

---

> Also is it possible to get convert my results into binary format so that it would be easier when trying to plot the data?

Yes it's possible however I don't see how that makes anything easier.

Comment: Changing the println function really worked for me thank you! I prefer to change the codes into binary so that it could help with my data plotting (possibly graph). What kind of code could I use to change it into binary?

Comment: @JonnyL That's another, different question.